# asp.net organize data in folders

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement in an ASP.NET 4.0 application to organize a list of tasks into folders. The folders are nested and can have a depth of up to 20 levels. Each task can be assigned to a folder at any level,
I look at treeview control but no way to dynamically add/delete nodes.

Any Ideas

thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's no way to add nodes dynamically? [Did you see this?](http://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview)

Comment: Hi Thanks for that but it is windows treeview not asp.net web forms

Comment: Yes, it's the .NET control which will also work in ASP.NET. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site has a working demo and a download link for the code:

[ASP.NET TreeView - Add to Dynamic Subtrees](http://www.obout.com/t2/ex_add_to_dynamic.aspx)

Comment: Thank you rick I will investigate this further tomorrow

Comment: Hi Rick I investigated the product but they dont give source code etc-You know any case where they do